# Android webview opens page in default browser instead of my webview

Tags: android, browser, webview

I am trying for two days to find a code to work with what I have.. I am following this tutorial: http://techvalleyprojects.blogspot.ro/2011_08_01_archive.html

I have the following problem: The webpage I want to open in my app is not loaded inside my webview, instead it opens in the default browser. How can I modify my code so that all links open in the webview. I need a easy solution because I am very new to Android..

Thank you.

```
package com.example.name;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
WebView browser;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // find the WebView by name in the main.xml of step 2
        browser=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.wvwMain);

        // Enable javascript
        browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);  

        // Set WebView client
        browser.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

        // Load the webpage
        browser.loadUrl("http://news.google.com/");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to implement `setWebViewClient(....)` like so.

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
                }
        });
```

### Update:

Make your **Activity** like so

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
WebView browser;

@Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // find the WebView by name in the main.xml of step 2
    browser=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.wvwMain);

    // Enable javascript
    browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);  

    // Set WebView client
    browser.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

    browser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
                }
        });
     // Load the webpage
    browser.loadUrl("http://news.google.com/");
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but where do I put the URL? Do I replace (url) with ("http://news.google.com/") ?

Comment: @AdrianM. wait i'll up date my answer.

Comment: Thanks, but I am getting 3 errors: -- Description Resource Path Location Type
The method shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView, String) of type new WebViewClient(){} must override or implement a supertype method MainActivity.java /name/src/com/example/name line 31 Java Problem
-- Description Resource Path Location Type
webView cannot be resolved MainActivity.java /name/src/com/example/name line 28 Java Problem
-- Description Resource Path Location Type
WebViewClient cannot be resolved to a type MainActivity.java /name/src/com/example/name line 28 Java Problem

Comment: @AdrianM. What is that? post it.

Comment: Please see above comment and thank your for your time and suggestions..

Comment: @AdrianM. `import android.webkit.WebViewClient;` in your `Activity` and also try this `browser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {....}`

Comment: That was the fix. Thank you so so so much :)

Comment: @AdrianM. yo welcome mate!

Answer (score 0):

Add this `setContentView(browser);`  instead of `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`, but add it at the end of the method.

Edit:

Also, add this:

```
   browser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {

            }
        });
```