# Webview Inside Fragment : How To Disable Open In Browser?

Tags: android, android-fragments, webview

I have this code and it works fine to open a web page :

```
package com.example.fragmenttabs;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.app.Fragment;

public class FragmentTab2 extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmenttab2, container, false);

        String url = "http://example.com";
        WebView view = (WebView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.webView2);        
        view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);          
        view.loadUrl(url);

        return rootView;
    }

}
```

but unfortunately, when I clicked on a link inside that webview, it will open Google Chrome. How to disable this behaviour? I want to make it open in same webview. not open in Google Chrome. thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android webview opens page in default browser instead of my webview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24035307/android-webview-opens-page-in-default-browser-instead-of-my-webview)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to implement `setWebViewClient(....)` like so.

```
 webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
            }
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

To open webivew link inside `webview` use  `setWebViewClient` as

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return false;
            }
    });
```

As stated in **document**,It Return **true** if the host application wants to leave the current WebView and handle the url itself, otherwise return **false**.

For more info see at [Webview shouldOverrideUrlLoading](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 2):

Implement WebViewClient() like:

```
 WebView _open;
 WebSettings webSettings = _open.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        _open.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
            }

        });
        _openpaypal.loadUrl(url);
```